# Oracle xmlquery - error when insert node?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle12c

I have a SQL

```
 SELECT  XMLQUERY
                  (
                    '
                      copy $res := $req
                      modify
                      insert node $xml as last into $res/validations/validation[code = $vid]
                      return $res
                    '
                    PASSING xmltype('
<validations>
  <validation>
    <code>1108</code>
    <severity>warning</severity>
    <description>DESC1</description>
    <status>1</status>
    <attributes>
      <attribute>
        <name>is-editable</name>
        <value>1</value>
      </attribute>
    </attributes>
  </validation>
  <validation>
    <code>762</code>
    <severity>warning</severity>
    <description>DESC2</description>
    <status>1</status>
    <attributes>
      <attribute>
        <name>is-editable</name>
        <value>1</value>
      </attribute>
    </attributes>
  </validation>
  <validation>
    <code>1281</code>
    <severity>warning</severity>
    <description>DESC3</description>
    <status>1</status>
    <attributes>
      <attribute>
        <name>is-editable</name>
        <value>1</value>
      </attribute>
    </attributes>
  </validation>
  <validation>
    <code>1281</code>
    <severity>warning</severity>
    <description>DESC3</description>
  </validation>
</validations>
')                                 AS "req",
                            1281 AS "vid",
                            (
                              SELECT  xmlelement("status",CASE 0
                                                            WHEN 0 THEN 1
                                                            WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                                            WHEN 2 THEN 2
                                                            WHEN 3 THEN 3
                                                            WHEN 4 THEN 4
                                                            WHEN 5 THEN 4
                                                            ELSE NULL
                                                          END
                                      )
                              FROM    dual
                            ) AS "xml"
                    RETURNING CONTENT
                  )

          FROM    dual;
```

first error is:

> ORA-18104: XUTY0005 - Invalid target expression for INSERT.

I assumed that is because of 2 nodes meet this condition code=1281,
so I deleted one, but another error is:

> ORA-21500: internal error code, arguments: [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With only one matching node your query seems to work, in the db<>fiddle 11gR2 and 18c versions anyway. The internal error code is therefore presumably a bug in your specific version and patch level.

You can update both matching nodes at once with a `for` expression:

```
SELECT  XMLQUERY
                  (
                    '
                      copy $res := $req
                      modify
                      for $n in $res/validations/validation[code = $vid]
                        return insert node $xml as last into $n
                      return $res
                    '
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9253848ff6477a06254d7933a2d19f5b)

The result from that, when formatted, ends up as:

```xml
...
    <validation>
        <code>1281</code>
        <severity>warning</severity>
        <description>DESC3</description>
        <status>1</status>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>is-editable</name>
                <value>1</value>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
        <status>1</status>
    </validation>
    <validation>
        <code>1281</code>
        <severity>warning</severity>
        <description>DESC3</description>
        <status>1</status>
    </validation>
</validations>
```

which presumably isn't quite what you want, as the first 1281 node now has two `status` nodes. You can skip any that already have a status with:

```
                      for $n in $res/validations/validation[code = $vid][not (status)]
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ca77d575d220ea19108d53973d279ec2)

The result from that, when formatted, now ends up as:

```xml
...
    <validation>
        <code>1281</code>
        <severity>warning</severity>
        <description>DESC3</description>
        <status>1</status>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>is-editable</name>
                <value>1</value>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </validation>
    <validation>
        <code>1281</code>
        <severity>warning</severity>
        <description>DESC3</description>
        <status>1</status>
    </validation>
</validations>
```